# Working with Ren.Py (Python), Syntax Errors

Tags: colors, renpy

I thought it would be nice for the player to pick their color.
My first attempt was:

```
define K = Character("Keeper")
define favcolor = (color="#ffffff")
define p1 = Character("Player1", (favcolor))


label start:
    K "Got a favorite color?"
    menu:
        "Blue":
            $ favcolor = color="#0033ff"
            jump Style
        "Red":
            $ favcolor = color="#ff3300"
            jump Style
        "Yellow":
            $ favcolor = color="#ffcc00"
            jump Style


label Style:
    p1 "Now I be styl'n"
```

but I get a syntax error. Likely because I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that an update has changed how this works. However, the following does work:

```
define K = Character("Keeper")
define E = Character('Eric', dynamic=True, color="#ffffff")

## The game starts here.

label start:

    K "Got a favorite color?"
    menu:
        "Blue":
            $ E = Character('Eric', color="#0000ff")
            jump Style
        "Red":
            $ E = Character('Eric', color="#ff3300")
            jump Style
        "Yellow":
            $ E = Character('Eric', color="#ffcc00")
            jump Style


label Style:
    E "Now I be styl'n"
```

I'll update the answer if, and when, I can find a better workaround.

Comment: I had totally given up on finding a solution for this, thank you so much.  My passion for finishing my project has been rekindled thanks to you.

Comment: @JonesCrimson You're welcome, I'm just glad I finally found a question I could answer properly. :)